# Is this strict inequality a typo in the characterization of jump continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation

I'm reading a proof about the characterization of jump continuous functions.

> $\textbf{Theorem}$ Let $I=[\alpha,\beta] \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $E$ a Banach space. Then $f:I \to E$ is jump continuous if and only if there is a sequence of staircase functions converging uniformly to $f$.
>
> [image]
> [image]

It seems to me that we only get $\left\|f-f_{n}\right\|_{\infty} \le 1 / n$ after taking the suppremum.

Could you please confirm if this strict inequality is a typo? Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it important? Does anything change if it is a typo? If needed one can work with $1/(n+1)$ at the beginning and then conclude the $<1/n$.

Comment: Hi @MoonLightSyzygy, I just want to verify if I understand the proof correctly.

Comment: That part is just taking $\sup_{x\in I}$. The immediate implication is $\leq 1/n$.